# Extra line breaks in email headers

Tags: regex, email, email-client, email-headers

I have a `webmail` system and for some time now have noticed that emails originating from a few servers come with an extra line break in the headers.

First was with the occasional `Dmarc` report from `Google`. About one a week.
Then other automated emails from `Bluebottle`. 
Other occasional come from various senders.

The extra line in the one from `Google` and `Bluebottle` it is always in the same place.
For the rest it's not. That is the problem.
I can run a nice `regex` to fix the ones that come in the same place but for the others I wouldn't like to tempt faith and cause more harm then good.

I have noticed major providers usually just don't bother with this, but I'd like to bother.

I have built this `regex`: `(\r[a-z-]*:.*)+(\r\r)+([a-z-]*:.*\r)+`
So far it seems to work, but I feel a bit concerned it might cause me problems.

Since regular expressions this broad are not recommended I would like some opinions if anyone has encountered this issue.

Comment: Your concern is legit. Why do you bother? Is this extra carriage return causing problems? And how are you using or do you intend to use this regex?

Comment: Well before I use this one I would like some feed-back if there is a better solution. This issue issue is causing problem with my automated Bounce, Unsubscribe and Dmarc processor since the break is in the automated emails not regular emails.

Comment: the rfc 822 says that there should be one CRLF after each row, and one CRLF before the message-body, so if you find 2 CRLF the rest should be the body, and if its header there, the sending software dons't folow rfc 822, in your regexp you have only CR (\r) witout LF (\n), and if that works, where did all your \n go?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I used \r only due to the limitation in this nice tool http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month of testing.

This appears to work quite well without issues so far.

```
$data = preg_replace("/(\r\n)([a-z-]*)(:)(.*)(\r\n)(\r\n)([a-z-]*):(.*)(\r\n)/i", "$1$2$3$4$6$7$8$9", $data);
```